# Listing field name aliases in one shapefile/layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, list, alias

I want to use arcpy/python to print out a list of all the field name aliases for a specified shapefile.  So far I have been able to hack a script I found to list all the field name aliases associated with every layer file on my map, but I wish for it to reference one specific shapefile.  Here's what I have so far:

Code:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
    print lyr.name
    fields =  desc.fields
    for field in fields:
        print field.aliasName
```

The above returns a list of all field alias names for ALL of the layers in the map.  I want to return just a list for ONE shapefile.

How would I go about referencing just one shapefile/layer in a map document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the whole list returned by [`ListLayers`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s30000002n000000), pass in the wildcard parameter using your layer name and just process the first item, e.g.

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "layer_name")[0]
desc = arcpy.Describe(lyr)
print lyr.name
fields =  desc.fields
for field in fields:
    print field.aliasName
```

Comment: excellent.  I was looking at the wildcard parameter but wasn't quite sure as to how to use it properly.  many thanks!

Comment: Just tried it.  It executes perfectly, but it returns a list of the field names--not the alias name of the field.  Interesting...

Comment: Are you sure they have aliases?

Comment: Yes.  The reason I know this is because if I run the code as I had originally, it generates all the field name aliases for that layer (the one I want) plus all the other layers that I don't want.  I just want to print out the alias names for the specific layer.

Comment: Well there is no functional difference between the code you posted and the code I posted except which layer(s) are being processed, so I would check to see that you haven't overlooked something (are there two similarly named layers, for example?).

Comment: The @blah238--your answer is correct.  Turns out that when I exported out this shapefile from a gdb, it stripped the alias name.  I guess...kind of weird but they aren't there any more.  Works for other layers that have the aliases there though.

Comment: Field aliases are not supported with shapefiles: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//0001000004pw000000